# If variance of overlapping sums > variance of underlying?

Tags: distributions, variance, random-variable

Starting with a sample series $x_1, ..., x_n$, I generate overlapping sums $y_i = \sum(x_i,...,x_{i+9})$.

If $X$ ~ Normal then it appears that $Var(Y) \approx 10 \times Var(X)$.

But for samples from an unknown stochastic process $X$ I am discovering that $Var(Y) > 10 \times Var(X)$.  What does this tell us about $X$?  For example, does it say something about higher moments of $X$?  Or perhaps the presence of autocorrelation in the process?

(For verification: in this case if I look at *non-overlapping* values $Y'$ = $y_1, y_{10}, ...$ then I do find that $Var(Y') = 10 \times Var(X)$.)

Comment: The variances should add if the $X_i$ are uncorrelated. How did you show that $Var(Y)>10\times Var(X)?$

Comment: @Dave I just computed the variances, as described, using the sample data series I have.  I suspect that the sample data are indeed correlated, but I am wondering what else (if anything) this observation about the variance of overlapping sums can tell us about the distribution or process of the sample data.

Comment: It feels like there's a clever triangle inequality to be had here.  I can't think of a process that generates values where the overlapping sum of the values produces a scaled variance < the variance of the values.